# replace a substring with a non-string value in python

Tags: python, string, replace

I know we have a replace method to replace a substring within a string with another string. But what I want is to replace some substring within a given string with some non-string (could be any data type) values.

example -

```
string1='My name is val1. My age is val2 years. I was born on val3'
val1='abc'
val2=40
val3= datetime.date(1980, 1, 1)
```

Any ideas??

Thanks!!

Comment: All values you want to replace `val1`, `val2` and `val3` with have to have a string representation if you want them to be in `string1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the value to string first:

```
>>> string1.replace("val2", str(val2))
'My name is val1. My age is 40 years. I was born on val3'
```

Comment: thank you all for your answers. many of the suggested ways worked, but I have voted for the one that suited my code requirement.

Answer (score 5):

Use `str.format`:

```
>>> string1 = 'My name is {0}. My age is {1} years. I was born on {2}'
>>> string1.format('abc', 40, datetime.date(1980, 1, 1))
'My name is abc. My age is 40 years. I was born on 1980-01-01'
```

Comment: [Aaron Digulla's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681574/replace-a-substring-with-a-non-string-value-in-python/6681776#6681776) shows how to use `format` with a dictionary to produce very readable code.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to use a dict for that because it makes it much more simple to see which argument goes where:

```
'My name is {val1}. My age is {val2} years. I was born on {val3}'.format(
    val1 = 'abc',
    val2 = 40,
    val3 = datetime.date(1980, 1, 1)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
string1='My name is %s. My age is %s years. I was born on %s'
print(string1 % ('abc', 40, datetime.date(1980, 1, 1)))
```

results in:

```
'My name is abc. My age is 40 years. I was born on 1980-01-01'
```